# Extracting data from url with a .txt in it

Tags: python, url

Please how can I save those 3 data as variable such **lat, lon, action** so as to use it back in the code

NB: The output change due to location sensors in an MIT APP I created

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://op-dev.icam.fr/~icam/projet.txt'

request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

print(response.read().decode('utf8'))
```

this is the output:

```
3.9714
9.79328
FOLLOW ME
```

Comment: Just split on new line and you get an array of 3 items

Answer (score 0):

```
res = response.read().decode("utf8")
parts = res.split("\n")
lat, lon, action = parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]
```

Or more pythonic way

```
res = response.read().decode("utf8").strip() # need to get rid of last newline
lat, lon, action = res.split("\n")
```